# How should I access logger from other methods within the same class?

Tags: ruby, logging, scope

I am trying to add a logger to my ruby app. The way I have it set up at the moment, the logger is created in the initialise method of my class. I then try to access it from other methods within the same class, but I get a scope error, specifically:

```
undefined local variable or method "logger" (NameError)
```

This refers to my first call to the logger method. How do I access my previously created logger from other methods?

Here is the full code:

[gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/05e05c374b054accb95cfa9eb125f4e5)

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be an instance variable? Try changing logger to @logger so that it is accessible across the class instance.

Comment: Thanks! This was part of the issue, but didn't solve it completely. The whole thing needs to be in it's own class.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If you want the logger variable to stay static to all instances of the class you can define it as @@logger

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own issue after searching around some more. To anyone with a similar issue, the best way to add the logger is in it's own class, structured like this:

```
class Log
    def self.log
        if @logger.nil?
            # CREATE LOGGER HERE
        end
        @logger
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this too:
@logger ||= Logger.new('logfile.log')

That ||= is the same as your if statement only creating that variable if it is nil.

Comment: Great! Even more concise!